# Ошибка при создании текстового редактора в Python

Tags: python

В этом коде:

```
import os
from tkinter import Tk, scrolledText, Menu, filedialog, END, messagebox, simpledialog
import tkinter.scrolledText as scrolledText

# Root for main window
root = Tk(className=" Text Editor")
textArea = scrolledText.scrolledText(root, width=100, height=80)


# Functions

def newFile():
    # Contect is here
    if len(textArea.get('1.0', END + '-1c')) > 0:
        if messagebox.askyesno("Save?", "Do you want to save?"):
            saveFile()


    else:
        textArea.delete('1.0', END)

    root.title("TEXT EDITOR")


def openFile():


 textArea.delete('1.0', END)
file = filedialog.askopenfile(parent=root, title='Select a text file...', fileTypes = (("textFile", "*.txt"), ("All files", "*.*")))

root.title(os.path.basename(file.name) + " - TEXT EDITOR")

if file != None:
    contents = file.read()
    textArea.insert('1.0', contents)
    file.close()


def saveFile():
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w')

    if file != None:
        data = textArea.get('1.0', END + '-1c')
        file.write(data)
        file.close()


def findInFile():
    findString = simpledialog.askstring("Find...", "Enter text...")
    textData = textArea.get('1.0', END)

    occurances = textData.upper.count(findString.upper())

    label = messagebox.showinfo("Results", findString + "has multiple occurances," + str(occurances))

    if textData.upper.count(findString.upper()) > 0:
        print(textData.upper.count(findString.upper()))

    else:
        label = messagebox.showinfo("Results", "Nooo, sorry Man ")


def about():
    label = messagebox.showinfo("About", "A Python is similar to Notepad++")


def exitRoot():
    if messagebox.askyesno("Quit", "Are you rly sure?"):
        root.destroy()


# menu options
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
fileMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.addcascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
fileMenu.add_command(label="New", command=newFile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Open", command=openFile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Save", command=saveFile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Settings...")
fileMenu.add_command(label="Find", command=findInFile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Print")
fileMenu.add_separator()
fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=exitRoot)

helpMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.addcascade(label="Help")
menu.addcascade(label="About", command=about)

textArea.pack()

# keep window open
root.mainloop()
```

Выдает ошибку:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'scrolledText' from 'tkinter'
>          (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py)

Comment: `import tkinter.scrolledtext as ScrolledText`

Comment: Во-первых, достаточно и трех строчек было, во-вторых, убери импорт scrolledText из второй строки. Нет такого. О чем ошибка и сообщает.